# Memory efficiency when exposing C struct with Cython

Tags: python, memory, cython

I am looking to use Cython to reduce the memory requirements of a data structure that is stored in a Python dictionary millions of times. Right now, I have implemented this as a simple Cython class in a pyx file:

```
cdef class FooBar:
    cdef public int x
    cdef public int y

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

I use this in another pyx file to populate a Python dictionary that has millions of keys:

```
python_dict[key] = FooBar(x, y)
```

This provides a substantial memory savings compared to using a namedtuple or other Python solution as my actual class stores 6 integers and thus required 40 bytes of memory (6*4 + 16 bytes for PyObject_Head). However, the 16 bytes overhead is substantial and my question is if there is a better way to do this. My understanding is that I can't directly expose a C struct since this would be type cast to a Python dictionary requiring far more memory. The python_dict dictionary is used extensively in my primarily Python code. Is there a way to avoid the PyObject_Head overhead without having to move a lot of the implementation over to pure Cython/C?

Comment: Hmm, what type of keys are you using? Could you go with a `numpy` structured array? I guess you likely want the performance characteristics of a `dict` though, but structured arrays are probably the most memory efficient way of storing this sort of data in Python

Comment: My gut says that at the end of the day, you need to have PyObjects as values in your dict. Which also implies that you require an extra machine word (probably 8 bytes) per value you are storing in your dict, since a dict always stores essentially pointers to a PyObject. It may just be worth the effort of implementing in Cython some sort of mapping that allows you to side-step this. Guess all stuff that one learns about hashing actually come in handy...

Comment: In Python, using `__slots__` is supposed to be significant memory saver, since stores the values 'directly' rather than using a `__dict__`.

Comment: @hpaulj that's not going to help here, `__slots__` will essentially give you what the OP already has with their `cdef class FooBar`  or what you might gain with a `namedtuple`, not having `__slots__` won't affect the PyObject_Header. What the OP needs is a `dict` that can directly hold a C struct, but that just isn't possible, since Python `dict` objects must hold references (i.e. pointers) to PyObjects, and those PyObjects require the PyObject_Header (in total for the pointer and the PyObject_Header that's 16 + 8 superfluous bytes) A numpy structured array would be ideal from a memory POV

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I was originally using a named tuple. This requires 96 bytes to store the 6 integers. This is better than I expected since a Python integer is 28 bytes so I was expecting the named tuple to be 6*28 = 168 bytes. I'm guessing each integer in a named tuple only uses 12 bytes (8 bytes for integer, 8 bytes for a pointer) and then there is a single PyObject_Header on top of this. At any rate, this is worse than the 40 bytes using Cython. I will look into using a numpy structured array though I am currently making extensive use the interface provided by a dictionary.

Comment: @DonovanParks how were you calculating that? Did you use a simple `sys.getsizeof(my_nametuple_instance)`? If so, you were leaving out the size of the actual integers! Of course, CPython caches small integers...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks! Yes, I wasusing sys.getsizeof() and did not understand how this worked.